# Service Bus 1.0 Beta New-SBFarm : The specified directory service attribute or value does not exist

Tags: powershell, servicebus

I am trying to register a new SB Farm following the procedure from  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj193021(v=azure.10).aspx

However when I try to execute the first part 
    $mycert= ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force -String 'password1'
    New-SBFarm -FarmMgmtDBConnectionString "data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated 
    Security=True;" –CertAutoGenerationKey $mycert

I receive the following error:

New-SBFarm : The specified directory service attribute or value does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-SBFarm -FarmMgmtDBConnectionString "data
source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-SBFarm], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException,Micr
   osoft.ServiceBus.Commands.NewSBFarm

I have ensured my server meets the application requirements, however I am still no luck...

Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

That line contains two separate cmdlet calls, one to create the secure string, and the second to create the new farm. Are you executing each call separately? From the pasted code, it seems like you're running them as one command, which would probably fail.

Also, the New-SBFarm has a switch to show verbose tracing. Could you try running the command with -verbose at the end and share the output?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm excuting the calls separately just my poor SO formatting.  I tried adding -verbose at the end of the call but got the same response

Comment: New-SBFarm -FarmMgmtDBConnectionString "data source=.\SQ
LEXPRESS;Integrated Security=True;" -CertAutoGenerationKey $mycert -verbose
New-SBFarm : The specified directory service attribute or value does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-SBFarm -FarmMgmtDBConnectionString "data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated
Secu ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-SBFarm], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException,Micr
   osoft.ServiceBus.Commands.NewSBFarm

Comment: I'm guessing the weird spacing is due to stackoverflow's comment weirdness. Where are you installing the server, is this a domain joined machine, or are you on a workgroup? Also, on the event viewer, there's a provider created for Microsoft-ServiceBus on the Application and Services section. The Admin channel might have more information about what's wrong.

Comment: Couldn't get it to work. I gave up and used rabbitmq.  Thank you